# NSCF type value into UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone

I'm trying to set array values in UITableViewCell at cellAtRowIndexPath - method, but it's giving the exception

```
[NSCFType objectAtIndex:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x445e980'
2011-05-26 13:34:12.812 addressBook[2603:20b] Stack: (
    9180251,
```

the values in 'people' array is of type 'NSCF'. I guess, it have to convert in to NSString. how will I show the vaues of 'people' array in tableviewcell? here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    people = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);
    NSLog(@"people....%@",people );
    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    // Set up the cell...
    cell.text = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: can you give the structure of object you have in address array?

Comment: Also, is adress reallly an array?

Comment: What is `people`? It doesn't seem to contain strings.

Comment: @deepak : people array contain people....(
    <NSCFType: 0x445e760>,
    <NSCFType: 0x445e840>,
    <NSCFType: 0x4460f90>,
    <NSCFType: 0x44610e0>,
    <NSCFType: 0x4461cb0>
)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`people` array is an array of `ABPerson` objects and not strings. So you can't assign it to as a string. You will have to process the record and get the name before assigning it to cell's `textLabel`.

```
ABRecordRef person = (ABRecordRef)[contacts objectAtIndex:0];
CFStringRef nameString = ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person);
cell.textLabel.text = (NSString*)nameString;
CFRelease(nameString);
```

Comment: i have so many contacts in address book so i made little bit variation in your code. Indeed i need to show individual contact in unique row.

Answer (score 0):

`objectAtIndex:` is NSArray instance method which you are calling at NSString (address)

EDIT: If you are sure people contains NSArray or a subclass of it, then do its enumeration and not NSString. You cannot use instance method of NSArray class for NSString instances. Hence, it is not recognized.

Answer (score 0):

Address is a string(there is no `objectAtIndex:` method)
Just remove for loop, use :

```
cell.text = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: giving exception "-[NSCFType isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x445e760
2011-05-26 14:01:07.612 addressBook[2753:20b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[NSCFType isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x445e760'

Comment: are you using cell.text = [people objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Please specify what is data type of "people"?

Comment: cell.text = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: i get values in people array from this buch line of code ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
 people = (NSArray *)ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);